# How to get content of div ( from external url) without loading the whole website

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the content of a div from an external url, but i don't want to load the whole website. Because i have to load a lot of data from many websites and it has to be very fast...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? - Don't expect us to do all the foot work for you.

Comment: Well, there are different ways to get the content from an external url, (like file get contents) but i can't find a way to load only one div

Comment: Try some php parser like PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it using php aswell

```
<?php 
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  //hides errors from invalid tags
     $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp');
     $DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $DivContent = $DOMxpath->query("//a[@class='menu_default']");
     var_dump($DivContent->item(0)->textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

check .load() function in [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/load/) .
sample :

```
$( "#result" ).load( "test.html #container" );
```

Comment: I tried the example in the API page but it  is not working for external url like :`<ol id="new-projects"></ol>
 
<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "http://api.jquery.com/resources/load.html #projects li" );
</script>`

Comment: what was the error you faced when you tried it ? maybe you got origin error . also if you want to try with php or c# , you can use web crawling libraries like `HtmlAgilityPack` .